# Why does Java HashMap need to increase or decrease when it can use chaining

Tags: java, hashmap, collision

If Java HashMap uses chaining to handle collisions why does it ever need to resize the hashtable for new keys to be added? As in what is the use of specifying the load factor as there is no need to increase or decrease the size of the HashTable from its initial capacity, right? For a fixed initial capacity the chains would just keep growing, won't they?

I understand it will increase the look up time to O(n) but I guess my question really is, HashMap must decide to double its size based on the length of the chain and not based on how full the hashtable is (also called load factor)?

Comment: "I understand it will increase the look up time to O(n)" If you are right, then this might very well be the reason - constant lookup time is really useful.

Comment: @tibetiroka just making sure I understood. So HashMap does handle collisions by chaining. However, if the load factor (number of keys/slots) is reached it resized to be able to still serve O(1) thereby trying to maintain a smaller chain size. Is that right?

Comment: What do you mean by "chain"? The "list" of items put into an individual bucket for colliding hashes? Javas `HashMap` is much more sophisticated than you might think, it maintains its buckets as Red-Black-Tree and not just as a simple list. If you really want to understand all effects of the _load factor_, you will have to read the source code. https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java

Comment: @Zabuzard yes by chain I mean the list of items put into an individual buckets for colliding hashes. Well, while Java may maintain it in a more optimal structure than list, the confusion mainly was I was thinking chaining and increasing the table size are mutually exclusive. As in if you increase or decrease the size of the hashtable you dont need chaining at all. So wondered why Java does both.

Comment: Because you have to make a tradeoff. Lets say you have 100k elements stored in your map and just 2 of them collide. Does that justify making a >200k big table and copying everything over? Not really. It is much better to keep a few collisions next to each other in a list/array/red-black-tree than to resize all the time. But if the collisions get out of hand and the buckets grow in size, you will want to resize to keep things fast. For the cost of extra space.

Comment: Resizing when collisions occur only helps if different hash values map to the same bucket before resizing but no longer after resizing. But if two values have the same hash code (the full 32 bits, for example the strings "aa" and "bB") then no amount of resizing helps to solve the conflict.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, a HashMap does not need to dynamically resize. There is a constructor parameter, `loadFactor`, that can be used to configure how aggressively HashMap resizes. You could in theory create a HashMap that never resizes like this:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> badMap = new HashMap<>(100, Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
```

But, as you have also noted, such a map would have `O(n)` access time, as each "bucket" would grow proportional to the total size of the map. Therefore you shouldn't do this!

Answer (score 0):

> I guess my question really is, HashMap must decide to double its size based on the length of the chain and not based on how full the hashtable is (also called load factor)?

For one thing, the load factor is the same thing as the average chain length, so in that sense, `HashMap` *does* use the chain length to make the decision.

Perhaps you mean that `HashMap` should use the maximum chain length rather than the average, but this is not viable for a general-purpose implementation.  Consider in particular the perverse case of instances of this class:

```
public class HashBuster {
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

That's a perfectly valid `hashCode()` method, and consistent with `equals()`, but if you store instances in a `HashMap` then they will always all go in the same bucket.  Rehashing will not change that, so you will end up with an unbounded series of rehashings if you use a fixed maximum chain length as your criterion for rehashing.  And if you use the proportion of maximum chain length to number of buckets, then that's bounded by the average chain length, so you're back to the load factor.

Also, in cases where objects are not necessarily all grouped in the same bucket, it may happen to be the case that a particular rehashing *increases* the maximum chain length instead of decreasing it.  That's pretty unlikely with a good hash function, but a non-negligible risk for plausible poor hash functions.

Comment: thanks but from the Java docs I see this. "The load factor is a measure of how full the hash table is allowed to get before its capacity is automatically increased". So I was of the understanding that load factor is not about the average chain length but how full the hashtable is allowed to get. Is this incorrect?